# USB 2 prober for mac?

Tags: macos, usb, libusb, sniffer

I'm trying to write a little driver for a [Tengu](http://www.tengutengutengu.com/) usb device.  I tried using USB Prober.app but it seems it can only probe USB 1 devices (my old Logitech mouse can be probed). Is it possible to sniff USB 2 data on Mac?